# Default value with an apostrophe in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where I am trying to give a default value as follows:

```
Create Table tblCompInd(
pref_code nvarchar2(10) default N'D' NULL
)
```

But it is failing because of `default N'D'` as it has apostrophe.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Try again removing the `NULL`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks, but your word was already enough (I saw many of your posts and obviously you are quite proficient in DBs :-)).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the **exact** error message you get. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Hello All,
First of all sorry.I had copied and pasted a small part of the table(only one column) and the table was actually very big(no table can have just one column!).
I actually had issues in other part of the creation of the table which got sorted.
I am extremely sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

The literal `N'D'` is specifying a character constant [for a nvarchar value](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA) and is perfectly legal.

What is wrong ,is the use of curly braces (`{`, `}`) in your statement. The correct statement is:

```
Create Table tblCompInd
(
   pref_code nvarchar2(10) default N'D' NULL
);
```

Online example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=322f8e029afe0eca7b8314c1dd9b18bf

Comment: The brackets were a mistake as i had written the code instead of copying,now i have copied the exact same code.

Comment: @VikeshGupta: so what is the error message you get?